# local JSON results are not shwoing - Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a local JSON file that contains a list of words and I want to display the words in a list using flutter/Dart, for some reason the results are not displayed. All I get is a blank page along with this exception:

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state:
>   I/flutter (25570): _FutureBuilderState#b10bc):

This is the code I am working with:

```
class _ListContentState extends State<ListContent> {

  List<WordsDictionary> _words = List<WordsDictionary>();

  Future<List<WordsDictionary>> _getWords() async{
    var dictionaryData = await 
    DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/json/dictionary.json');
    var words = List<WordsDictionary>();
    if(dictionaryData != null){
      var jsonData = json.decode(dictionaryData);
      for(var word in jsonData){
        words.add(WordsDictionary.fromJson(word));
      }
    }else {
      print('fail');
    }
    return words;
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    _getWords().then((value) {
      setState(() {
       _words.addAll(value); 
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            elevation: 6.0,
             child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0, bottom: 6.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(_words[index].wordEnglish,),
                  Spacer(),
                  Text(_words[index].wordGerman,),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
      },
      itemCount: _words.length,
    );
  }
}
```

**WordDictionary.dart** :

```
class WordsDictionary {
  int wordId;
  String wordEnglish;
  String wordGerman;

  WordsDictionary(
    this.wordId,
    this.wordEnglish, 
    this.wordGerman
  );

  WordsDictionary.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    wordId = json['wordId'];
    wordEnglish = json['englishWord'];
    wordGerman = json['germanWord'];
  }
}
```

Comment: did you add the line to pubspec file

Comment: @MuratAslan yes I did

Comment: Would you mind post your `WordsDictionary` class? The error mean If you have a variable that called a method doesn't exist, you would get this error, and post more errors from console would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you just return `Future.value([WordsDictionary(123, "English", "Germal")])` from   `_getWords` to check if problem with display or fetching json?

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap your list view with future builder 
I slightly change your WordsDictionary class

example json

```
[
{
    "wordId" : "1",
    "wordEnglish" : "abc",
    "wordGerman" : "def"
},
{
    "wordId" : "2",
    "wordEnglish" : "123",
    "wordGerman" : "456"
}
]
```

the following is full working code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final wordsDictionary = wordsDictionaryFromJson(jsonString);

List<WordsDictionary> wordsDictionaryFromJson(String str) =>
    List<WordsDictionary>.from(
        json.decode(str).map((x) => WordsDictionary.fromJson(x)));

String wordsDictionaryToJson(List<WordsDictionary> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class WordsDictionary {
  String wordId;
  String wordEnglish;
  String wordGerman;

  WordsDictionary({
    this.wordId,
    this.wordEnglish,
    this.wordGerman,
  });

  factory WordsDictionary.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      WordsDictionary(
        wordId: json["wordId"],
        wordEnglish: json["wordEnglish"],
        wordGerman: json["wordGerman"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "wordId": wordId,
        "wordEnglish": wordEnglish,
        "wordGerman": wordGerman,
      };
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ListContent(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class ListContent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListContentState createState() => _ListContentState();
}

class _ListContentState extends State<ListContent> {
  List<WordsDictionary> _words = List<WordsDictionary>();

  Future<List<WordsDictionary>> _getWords() async {
    var dictionaryData = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
        .loadString('assets/json/dictionary.json');
    var words = List<WordsDictionary>();
    if (dictionaryData != null) {
      words = wordsDictionaryFromJson(dictionaryData);
      print("words lenght ${words.length}");
    } else {
      print('fail');
    }
    return words;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<WordsDictionary>> wordSnap) {
        switch (wordSnap.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return new Text('none');
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
          case ConnectionState.active:
            return new Text('');
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (wordSnap.hasError) {
              return new Text(
                '${wordSnap.error}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: wordSnap.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    WordsDictionary wordsDictionary = wordSnap.data[index];
                    return Card(
                        elevation: 6.0,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 6.0, bottom: 6.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                          child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                wordsDictionary.wordEnglish,
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                wordsDictionary.wordGerman,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ));
                  });
            }
        }
      },
      future: _getWords(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I still got a blank screen, the data is not showing

Comment: could you post error message when use my code? thanks

Comment: maybe because you use wordEnglish = json['germanhWord']; and I use wordEnglish: json["wordEnglish"], , could you change this part to fit your json string?

Comment: I don't really get any errors, it's just the `ConnectionState` doesn't go to `done` and the circular progress just stays spinning